Using pytorch, how to estalish a loss function to keep all kernal to be exactly same
For exmaple, you have a CNN of 3 layers, every layer has only 1 channal(1 output features), so the weights of the CNN are 3 kernals, 1 for each layer. Assume these 3 kernals all are 221, and how can we define a loss for backprogogation to keep them identical? Or maybe some other optimazation approach to let that happen?
I tried to average them to be a target of kernal, but all kernal goes to zeros.
import torch
import torchvision 
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(
            #The size of the picture is 28x28
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 1,out_channels = 16,kernel_size = 3,stride = 1,padding = 1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2,stride = 2),
            
            #The size of the picture is 14x14
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 16,out_channels = 32,kernel_size = 3,stride = 1,padding = 1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2,stride = 2),
            
            #The size of the picture is 7x7
            torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 32,out_channels = 64,kernel_size = 3,stride = 1,padding = 1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            
            torch.nn.Flatten(),
            torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 7 * 7 * 64,out_features = 128),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Linear(in_features = 128,out_features = 10),
            torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )
        
    def forward(self,input):
        output = self.model(input)
        return output
        
        
device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
transform = torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean = [0.5],std = [0.5])])
      
BATCH_SIZE = 256
EPOCHS = 10
trainData = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data/',train = True,transform = transform,download = True)
testData = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data/',train = False,transform = transform)


trainDataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = trainData,batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,shuffle = True)
testDataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset = testData,batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
net = Net()
print(net.to(device))

lossF = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters())

history = {'Test Loss':[],'Test Accuracy':[]}
for epoch in range(1,EPOCHS + 1):
    processBar = tqdm(trainDataLoader,unit = 'step')
    net.train(True)
    for step,(trainImgs,labels) in enumerate(processBar):
        trainImgs = trainImgs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        net.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(trainImgs)
        loss = lossF(outputs,labels)
        predictions = torch.argmax(outputs, dim = 1)
        accuracy = torch.sum(predictions == labels)/labels.shape[0]
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        processBar.set_description("[%d/%d] Loss: %.4f, Acc: %.4f" % 
                                   (epoch,EPOCHS,loss.item(),accuracy.item()))
        
        if step == len(processBar)-1:
            correct,totalLoss = 0,0
            net.train(False)
            with torch.no_grad():
                for testImgs,labels in testDataLoader:
                    testImgs = testImgs.to(device)
                    labels = labels.to(device)
                    outputs = net(testImgs)
                    loss = lossF(outputs,labels)
                    predictions = torch.argmax(outputs,dim = 1)
                    
                    totalLoss += loss
                    correct += torch.sum(predictions == labels)
                    
                    testAccuracy = correct/(BATCH_SIZE * len(testDataLoader))
                    testLoss = totalLoss/len(testDataLoader)
                    history['Test Loss'].append(testLoss.item())
                    history['Test Accuracy'].append(testAccuracy.item())
            
            processBar.set_description("[%d/%d] Loss: %.4f, Acc: %.4f, Test Loss: %.4f, Test Acc: %.4f" % 
                                   (epoch,EPOCHS,loss.item(),accuracy.item(),testLoss.item(),testAccuracy.item()))
    processBar.close()
    



torch.save(net,'./model.pth')


I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking but you don't need to use optimization to keep the parameters of two different modules of the network the same, just define it like self.some_module = nn.Linear(foo, bar) in the __init__ and then use the forward method to define how you want the layers arranged, i.e. output = some_module(x) then output = some_other_module(output).

you wrote: "a CNN of 3 layers, every layer has only 1 channal(1 output features),". This does not seem to match your code, were you have out_channels = 16, out_channels = 32 and out_channels = 64. Please clarify
